# pip install onnxruntime==1.12.1 doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm trying to install that package version from pip, but it gives me the following error:

`pip install onnxruntime==1.12.1`

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement onnxruntime==1.12.1 (from versions: 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.16.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for onnxruntime==1.12.1
```

But onnxruntime==1.12.1 does in fact exist in pip: https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/1.12.1/

I've tried installing other versions too, but it throws the same error. Only versions 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.16.0 can be installed.

Comment: what version of python do you use? 1.12.1 wheels are for 3.7-3.10

Comment: python --version
Python 3.11.2, So I need to downgrade python version?

Comment: @CarlosDubón If you really need to use v1.12.1, yes. Only v1.15+ have Python 3.11 wheels.

Comment: @Brian61354270;@buran These links say that python 3.11 is supported https://github.com/onnx/onnx/releases/tag/v1.13.0 ; https://github.com/onnx/onnx/pull/4490 by `v1.13.0`

Comment: @Goku Those links are for a different project

Comment: @Brian61354270 these links are mentioned here https://pypi.org/project/onnxruntime/1.12.1/

Comment: @Goku You're mixing up https://github.com/onnx/onnx and https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/. `onnx` and `onnxruntime` are two different packages

Comment: @Goku, apart from mixing the two projects, there are at least two other issues - the 3.11 support in the package you refer to comes in version 1.13.0, and OP wants 1.12.1. the other - even if i was right one and hypothetically it says on GitHub it support 3.11 in version 1.12.1, on pypi there are only wheels for 3.7-3.10